# PowerShell - Copy zip file pass as string parameter to remote server

Tags: powershell, copy, zip

I am uploading zip file using .NET Core application and pass it as a string parameter to PowerShell script and trying to use following command for copy

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Param($uplodedZipFileAsString,$DestinationFilePath) New-Item -Path $DestinationFilePath -Value $uplodedZipFileAsString -Force }  -ArgumentList ($uplodedZipFileAsString, $DestinationFilePath)
```

using above command file is copied at destination location, but while tried to unzip it. it gives an error as

> The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'DestPath\uplodedZipFile.zip' is invalid.

**Question :-**

1. How can copy zip file(passed as string parameter) to remote server?
2. What are the best practices should follows in this scenario?

Note:- Assume that in above PowerShell command all parameters like $Session,$uplodedZipeFileAsString and $DestinationFolderFilePath are properly provided.

**Edited:-**

High level code details as follows

In .NET Core using file upload control we get *IFormFile file(argument name)* as parameter method looks as follows

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IFormFile file)
{
   // following method convert FileStream To Sting 
    string fileString = ConvertFileStreamToString(file); // this is zip as string

   //following method execute powershell script 
   PowerShellHelper(string fileString,... other paramter)

  //Other Code...
}

private string ConvertFileStreamToString(IFormFile file)
{
  var fileString = new StringBuilder();
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
  {
     while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        fileString.AppendLine(reader.ReadLine());
  }
  return fileString.ToString();
}
```

PowerShell as follows

```
 function zipcopyfunction
 {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   Param
   (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
            Position=0,
            HelpMessage='Please Provide Zip File')]
   [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
   [string]$uplodedZipFileAsString,
   #other necessary paramters goes here...
  )

 #Other code related to session creation
 try
 { 
   #other code including destination file path(DestinationFilePath) and $Session...
  $DestinationFilePath = "C:\test\destFile.zip"
  Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Param($uplodedZipFileAsString,$DestinationFilePath) New-Item -Path $DestinationFilePath -Value $uplodedZipFileAsString -Force }  -ArgumentList ($uplodedZipFileAsString, $DestinationFilePath)
  #remove session related code...
}
 catch
 {
      Throw $_.exception.message
  }
}
```

Comment: ..But a Zip file is not a string.. Show us how you 'stringyfied' that so we may help you with the code. Or did you mean `$uplodedZipFileAsString` is in fact the path to a file somewhere? BTW, in PowerShell arguments should be **space** separated, so `-ArgumentList ($uplodedZipFileAsString, $DestinationFilePath)` is wrong and should be `-ArgumentList $uplodedZipFileAsString $DestinationFilePath`

Comment: @Theo - I have added high level code which help to understand and about your comment related to -ArgumentList the above mentioned command working properly it is copying file at destination.(only problem is while copied zip file to destination it will unable to extract)

Comment: Yes, but that is because a zip file **is not a string**. Your high level code only works for files that are text files. A zip file is a **Binary** file which doesn't stringify like text (which uses characters in a certain encoding). What you need is to read the file as byte array

Comment: @Theo - yes. I thing you are right there is some problem in reading file as string. currently, I am trying to read zip as byte[] and converting it to string as "Encoding.Default.GetString(fileBytes)" and after that pass it to PowerShell. is it right way to do it?

Comment: No, you should not alter the bytes, but the function instead. Read the file as bytes and write them as bytes to file. Change `[string]$uplodedZipFileAsString` into something like `[byte[]]$ZipBytes` then send that as parameter to the scriptblock and have it write to a new file. Personally I would use `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($DestinationFilePath, $ZipBytes)`

Comment: Anyway, why can't you simply copy the file to the remote server? Something like `Copy-Item -Path 'X:\localpath\thezipfile.zip' -Destination '\\remoteservername\share\path' -Credential $cred` where `$cred` is a credentials object you get with `Get-Credential`

Comment: @Theo - yes, it is easy, but our functionality want user to upload zip file. that's why I can't do that

Comment: @Theo - could you please give example about byte[] as you explain in earlier chat. it would be more helpful. you can add it as answer I will accept it if it works! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, don't try to read a binary file as if it were a text file.

Instead, read the file as an array of bytes (`[Byte[]]`) to get the actual file content unaltered. Then you could change your code to do this:

```
# use the full, absolute filepaths as we're using .Net methods
$sourceFile   = 'D:\somewhere\TheFile.zip'

# the path (in this demo 'D:\Test') MUST exist locally in the remote machine
$destination  = 'D:\Test\TheFile.zip' 

# read the file as an array of Bytes 
[byte[]]$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($sourceFile)

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { 
    Param(
        [byte[]]$ZipBytes,
        [string]$DestinationFilePath
    ) 
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($DestinationFilePath, $ZipBytes)
} -ArgumentList @($bytes ,$destination)
```

<sup>You *could* convert the binary data into a string, by converting the data to Base64 for instance using `[Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)` but then in the scriptblock you will first need to convert that string back to bytes using `[byte[]]$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($uplodedZipFileAsString)` and then write to file. This of course will use more processing time and the data you will be sending wil become much larger than the original number of bytes.</sup>

Comment: Nice Theo, qq what would be the advantage of sending the data in b64 ? I'm guessing reliability ? As a plus, reg "sending will become much larger", gzip comes in very handy there

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I just added Base64 as example how the OP could convert the binary payload into a string safely and then convert back to bytes. I would go for the raw bytes, but since the OP seemed to be keen on stringifying...